# Spring class EnvironmentCapable

Tags: spring, class, package, environment

I received run-time error for string

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/env/EnvironmentCapable
```

I have checked jar org.springframework.core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar and doesnt' found this class. 
In which package this class? Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think that need use version 3.1.0 - in package org.springframework.core-3.1.0.M2.jar this class presents.

Answer (score 15):

That's a Spring 3.1 (still a milestone release) class. If you're intending to use Spring 3.0, you must have mixed in some 3.1 stuff accidentally.