# Spring's Java Based configuration not working for me

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

I am new to Spring programming and currently struggling with Spring 3.1's Java Based Configuraion" I have created following Configuration class

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:/resources/jdbc.properties")
public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;
    private @Value("${jdbc.url}")
    String url;
    private @Value("${jdbc.username}")
    String username;
    private @Value("${jdbc.password}")
    String password;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        System.out.println("Creating data Source.");
        return new DriverManagerDataSource(url, username, password);
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory () throws Exception {
        return new AnnotationSessionFactoryBuilder().setDataSource(dataSource()).setPackagesToScan("com.argusoft.loginmodule.domain").buildSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

now when I try to run the project I get following error.

**OUTPUT**

> SEVERE: Exception while loading the app :
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/core/env/EnvironmentCapable

stuck into it, Cant solve it..... I am following [Spring Source Blog](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/06/10/spring-3-1-m2-configuration-enhancements/).

please also suggest some good tutorial in which Spring's latest Java based configuration is explained by easy to understand examples...

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the perspective of the exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/env/EnvironmentCapable
```

This question is equals to the question: [Spring class EnvironmentCapable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726023/spring-class-environmentcapable)

So the correct answer might be:

> I think that need use version 3.1.0 - in package
>   org.springframework.core-3.1.0.M2.jar this class presents.

given by user810430 here: [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726023/spring-class-environmentcapable/6726117#6726117).

Comment: Given the OP mentions Spring 3.1, this reference to a previous question is not the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
you can puth configuration like this
inside application context:
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/configuration.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

<import resource="db-config.xml" />

and   
db-config.xml is:
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">

        <property name="driverClass">
            <value>${jdbc.driver.className}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="jdbcUrl">
            <value>${jdbc.url}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="user">
            <value>${jdbc.username}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>${jdbc.password}</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean" autowire="byName">
        <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.huawei.sa.album" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
                 <props>
                                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <!-- uncomment this for first time run-->
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>


    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>

       <tx:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

Comment: configuration properties:   jdbc.driver.className=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/albumserver
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=1234
jdbc.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

Comment: I really appreciate ur quick help.... but I need to do it using Annotations only... please suggest me ways to do this using Spring's latest annotations only....