# Spring application build failure

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

I am not able to figure out what is wrong while running **mvn spring-boot:run** command. **mvn clean install** gives a build success but for **mvn spring-boot:run** i get a build failure.
This is my error log in my console when i run **mvn spring-boot:run -X**.

```
    [WARNING]
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:506)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/env/EnvironmentCapable
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
            at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
            at com.example.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10)
            ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.env.EnvironmentCapable
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
            ... 18 more
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 10.024 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-11T15:24:36+05:30
    [INFO] Final Memory: 23M/223M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project demo: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: org/springframework/core/env/EnvironmentCapable: org.springframework.core.env.EnvironmentCapable -> [Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project demo: An exception occurred while running. null
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An exception occurred while running. null
            at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$IsolatedThreadGroup.rethrowUncaughtException(AbstractRunMojo.java:475)
            at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo.runWithMavenJvm(RunMojo.java:92)
            at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:234)
            at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:170)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
            ... 20 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:506)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/env/EnvironmentCapable
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
            at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
            at com.example.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10)
            ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.env.EnvironmentCapable
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
            ... 18 more
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

This is my pom.xml . I have also removed pom.xml from the active maven profiles in eclipse ide, cause it was given as one of the solutions in this link [Spring Maven clean error - The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28192761/spring-maven-clean-error-the-requested-profile-pom-xml-could-not-be-activate)

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>com.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>

      <name>Test</name>
      <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

      <parent>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
          <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
          <relativePath />      
      </parent>

      <properties>
          <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
          <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
          <java.version>1.8</java.version>
          <start-class>com.example.DemoApplication</start-class>
      </properties>

      <dependencies>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
          </dependency>


      </dependencies>

      <build>
      <pluginManagement>
          <plugins>
              <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              </plugin>

              <!-- <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              </plugin>  -->   
          </plugins>
          </pluginManagement>

      </build>
      </project>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245732/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-springframework-core-env-configurableenviron)

Answer (score 0):

first check your class names. maven plugin says com.example class not found!
what is  `<start-class>com.example</start-class>` in your pom.xml file?

Comment: I have edited my start class from `<start-class>com.example</start-class>` to `<start-class>com.example.DemoApplication</start-class>` But now i am getting a different error log. Please help.

Comment: i think it might be cause of dependency lack. change  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726023/spring-class-environmentcapable/6726117

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245732/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-springframework-core-env-configurableenviron

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after debugging the dependency management in pom.xml and what exclusions are required . So we need to include few exclusions in the dependency which will make this basic application run.
Here is my latest pom.xml which made it work .

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
                <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

                <groupId>ok.one</groupId>
                <artifactId>hello</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <packaging>jar</packaging>

                <name>hello</name>
                <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

                <parent>
                    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
                    <relativePath />
                </parent>

                <properties>
                    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
                    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
                    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
                    <start-class>ok.one.HelloApplication</start-class>
                </properties>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                                <!-- Exclusions to allow SpringBoot execute on HCP -->
                                <exclusions>
                                    <exclusion>
                                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                                    </exclusion>
                                    <exclusion>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
                                    </exclusion>
                                    <exclusion>
                                        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                                        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                                    </exclusion>
                                </exclusions>
                            </dependency>

                </dependencies>

                <build>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </build>


            </project>
```